# He's a real mama's baby

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Monday morning baby Alex awoke in his mother's loving embrace.  His mother changed him, fed him, and snuggled him, which he of course loved.  But when she went to get her coat and suitcase baby Alex got upset as he realized she was getting ready to leave him for work.  Not wanting her to go he cried and cried begging her to stay.  Unable to bear her son crying his mom swept him up into her arms to comfort the child.  To calm the upset child she promised she would stay with him today so he didn't have to be upset.

Every day after that the same routine happened.  Alex was happy and loving child until he saw his mother preparing to leave, at which point he would cry and cry until his mom promised to stay with him.  No matter what his mother tried or did she couldn't find any way to leave without upsetting her beloved son, but she knew she wouldn't make any money if she stayed home.

How did Alex's mom comfort him and keep him happy while still having enough money to pay for everything he needed?

> This isn't as open ended as it may seem...

> Alex's mom's solution is already clearly explained.

*updated hint*

> I was very specific in my wording for a reason...

*Adding minor hints*

> Ultimately Alex's mother went to work every day while Alex was comforted

> This is not actually an unusual situation, I've seen many a few parents doing the same thing.

and a bigger hint:

> You shouldn't make presumptions about Alex's family

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposed answer:

> Alex has (at least) 2 moms

Explanation:

Monday morning baby Alex awoke in his mother's loving embrace. His mother changed him, fed him, and snuggled him, which he of course loved. But when she went to get her coat and suitcase baby Alex got upset as he realized she was getting ready to leave him for work. Not wanting her to go he cried and cried begging her to stay.

> the above is regarding Mom 1  who ultimately left for work

Unable to bear her son crying his mom swept him up into her arms to comfort the child. To calm the upset child she promised she would stay with him today so he didn't have to be upset.

> the above is regarding Mom 2 who stayed home

How did Alex's mom comfort him and keep him happy while still having enough money to pay for everything he needed?

> She stayed home with him while his other mom left for work.  This situation can arise in various untraditional family forms. (at least untraditional for my specific culture/regional upbringing, can't speak for others).

Answer (score 4):

My answer:

> She took her baby with her to work.

Explanation:

> "Go to work" often plants the image of *office work* in people's heads. That's not the case for Alex's mom; she works at a daycare center, where she will be able to conveniently bring her child with her.

Comment: This is a very good idea that works perfectly with the hints given (other then one doesn't usually need a suitcase for that) so I'm upvoting it, but It isn't the idea I had in mind.  I'll have to think of a new hint to distinguish between something like this and what I had in mind...

Comment: @dsollen hints that add crucial clarifications to make a puzzle have a single solution aren't hints, they're vital parts of the puzzle. Ideally puzzles are uniquely solvable without any hints

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Well, initially Alex's mother knew she wouldn't make any money if she stayed home. But then year 2020 came, and the situation changed significantly. The COVID-19 pandemic stroke, and Alex's mother was transferred to a remote job due to quarantine restrictions, so she could both stay with him and work (from their home).

Comment: This sentence invalidates your answer: *"but she knew she wouldn't make any money if she stayed home."*

Answer (score 0):

The key line might be

> when she went to get her coat and suitcase Alex got upset as he realized she was getting ready to leave

So,

> His mother started storing her coat and suitcase in the bathroom. Each morning, she'd go into the bathroom, get ready for work, climb out the window, cross over to the garage, and climb down the rainspout to get to her car. In the evening, she'd return home by the same path.

Comment: Alex has got a Supermom! ;)

Comment: Boy, Alex will grow up to think his mom once used the rot13(onguebbz) 6 hours a time everyday!

Comment: @riskymysteries wait you mean most people don't do that?  Maybe I should consider seeing a doctor after all... :P

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer is,

> She promised to stay with him everyday.  But eventually left for work.

> The puzzle only says, she promised to stay with him, but does not confirm that she stayed.  So, she probably picked him up, promised him and made him sleep.  But after he slept she left to work.